# How to replace the first match only using .Net Regex.Replace

Tags: .net, regex

```
Regex.Replace("a b c a b c", "a", "*")
```

returns

```
"* b c * b c"
```

Is there a simple way to replace only the first occurence, such that the result is

```
"* b c a b c"
```

Cannot find a RegExOption that would limit the replacement. In particular

```
Regex.Replace("a b c a b c", "a", "*", RegexOptions.Multiline)
Regex.Replace("a b c a b c", "a", "*", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

do not make any difference - obviously. There are not much more options however.

Comment: is there any replaceFirst option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [appropriate overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("a");
string result = rgx.Replace("a b c a b c", "*", 1); // * b c a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing group along with the starting anchor.

```
Regex.Replace("a b c a b c", "^([^a]*)a", "$1*")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uS5qR5/3)

`^([^a]*)` captures all the characters which exists before the first `a`. And the following `a` on the above regex matches only the first `a`. So by replacing the matched chars with the characters present inside the group index 1 plus `*` will give you the desired output.